# Bug with the special characters in the email on Contact page

Tags: bug, status-review, email, contact, html-entities

I have an account with email like `user+somepart@gmail.com` (Not a real email).
I've visited the [Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), selected the contact variant (for example, `Account Issue` > `I need to merge user profiles`) and I see the HTML entity instead the right symbol:

[image: wrong email character, expected "+" but got "&#x2B"]

However I expected this:

[image: the right email]

Currently users have to edit the email field manually to contact.

Comment: Relevant: [What characters are allowed in an email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2049502/1014587)

Comment: Yup, I can repro. This bug is so common I never reported it, out of sheer exasperation.